# I'm having an issue with my google chrome extension, new to code so be basic please

Tags: json, google-chrome

I'm trying to make a google chrome extension, but I'm having a problem. Please answer as basic as possible as I'm really bad at code. Whenever I upload something as a zip file, it says

> "An error occurred: Failed to process your item. manifest.json:5:26:
>   unexpected char."

This is my code :

```
{
    "name": "ROBLOX Character Asset ID",
    "version": "1.9.0", // version
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description": "This extension is for GFX artists who need their customer's character asset ID", 
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png"

    },
    "permissions": [
        "alarms",
        "background",
        "debugger",
        "notifications",
        "cookies",
        "https://www.roblox.com/" 
    ],
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["bgWork.js", "jQuery-ver3.js"]
    },
    "icons": { "16": "icon.png",
           "48": "icon.png",
          "128": "icon.png" }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with the content in your scripts and when you load the extension it not being able to be processed as I loaded your manifest.json just fine (though with blank js files). So don't look towards your manifest.json, you must have an illegal character in your js file.